# How do I add files to posts?

Tags: support, formatting

I know how to add an image file in question post like this, but I need to add a very wide txt file and I am strugling for this.

Please, what I'm missing ?

If I click on image insertion button I can insert only image, but for the .txt?

Comment: Hey Emilio! Perhaps, consider using a pastebin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot attach a file, like you would in email. That isn’t supported. You have a few options:

- Use a [pastebin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin) - there are many if you search, [Ubuntu also has one](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/). Do read the note about pastebins below
- If it isn't too long, put it in a [code block](https://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Note: I would encourage anyone that thinks they need a file so big it won't fit in a code block to consider (1) if the question would be useful to others and (2) if that specific data is needed. For example, if it is just "How can I read a 12GB CSV file?", the specific contents of *your* CSV file is irrelevant. If the file contents really is important to the question, consider archiving the pastebin (or direct download, if one) with [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/) in case the original page goes away

But do consider this first: do you *really* need to include the entire file? Would your question be fine without it? If it isn't needed, don’t add it. Also, depending on the question, adding a portion of the file could work.

Comment: Great answer (as always)! The extra problem with Pastebins is that there is no guarantee that the information will *remain* for any particular time period. This means a dead link eventually and a loss of useful information from question,answer or comment. On the Ubuntu pastebin page I see: 'Submitted data is not guaranteed to be permanent, and may be removed at any time.' I am not sure if this is different in other pastebin services...

Comment: @andrew.46 I fully agree. The Wayback Machine could work for making them permanent, but... after thinking about it more, I'm not sure using pastebins is a good idea, even if they were permanent. IMO, questions should be fully self-standing, much like [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from SO. Code blocks are fine for including text files, and if content is so big a code block won't work then the question should probably made more general. IMO, if a question _really_ needs a specific big file, then it is most likely to not be useful to anyone but the OP.

Comment: I have bookmarked that 'Minimal, Reproducible Example ' in my 'Moderation' bookmarks, very useful!

Comment: @andrew.46 I know this would be a separate Meta post, but do you know if anyone has considered adding some portion of that page (a tl;dr probably) to our ["How do I ask a good question?" page](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask)? We have a "Make it relevant to others" section, but it just says to, it doesn't explain _how_ to

Comment: Hmmm... that whole AU page is a little soft on details isn't it :). I will give my colleagues a poke and get their input here...

Comment: @andrew.46 Do you mind if I made a Meta post about it? I have a few additional thoughts about it, but a separate post is probably easier than comments. Of course, I don't mind if you want to poke anyone, more input is better!

Comment: Go for it! Always good to see some action on Meta

Comment: Another issue with paste.ubuntu.com is that it seems to require an annoying login process these days. Have resorted to using Debian's pastebin...

Comment: Would be great to improve the Help Center page, but I must point out that it is rarely OP's fault that the output they want to include is too long, as most often it's the output from the [wireless info script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/527764) or boot-repair report (often requested by our community members). I have done all sorts of dodgy things to shorten the output of these to fit the character limit. I wonder if we could have a bigger character limit!

Comment: @Zanna I didn't consider that, but that makes sense. I guess you could make a Meta post for that, but is that something SE allows individual sites to change? Or is it one size limit across SE?

Comment: I don't know, I should think more and ask a CM!